# Why am I seeing this running after_cd message in the latest version of RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I just installed the latest version of RVM and when I open up a new Terminal I am seeing this `Running /Users/foo/.rvm/hooks/after_cd` message.

Is this the intended behaviour? Is there a way to suppress this message?

Comment: I don't see this message, but yes, this is how RVM operates internally. It hooks to `cd` command and changes rubies as you navigate the directory tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's second report I got about this problem, it's not yet known what causes it, but you can fix it with:

```
printf "rvm_verbose_flag=0\nrvm_debug_flag=0\n" >> ~/.rvmrc
```

if this does not fix it please open a ticket here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: What's the latest version that's known now to have this problem?

Comment: I do not think it's RVM code related, in my opinion it might be something in the system, maybe shell ... not sure, what system / shell are you using, any additions?